# yii2 ArrayHelper dropDownList

Tags: php, yii2

Controller

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $model = new FbToken();

    $listTokens = ArrayHelper::map(FbToken::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->getId()])->all(), 'token', 'name');

    return $this->render('index',[
        'model' => $model,
        'listTokens' => $listTokens,
    ]);
}
```

view

```
 <?php
            $form = ActiveForm::begin();
            echo   $form->field($model, 'token')->dropDownList($listTokens,
                ['onchange' => '$.post("'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(["site/adds"]).
                    '", 
                    {
                    token: $(this).val()
                    },
                    function( data ) {
                    $("#test_div").html( data );
                    })'
                ]);

            ActiveForm::end();
            ?>
```

Как сделать что бы первое в списке было Выберите значения ?

```
<select>
   <option>Выберите значения</option>
   <option value="1">name1</option>
   <option value="2">name2</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
$form->field($model, 'token')->dropDownList($listTokens, [
    'prompt' => 'Please select',
    'onchange' => '$.post(...)',
]);
```

Начиная с Yii **2.0.11**:

```php
$form->field($model, 'token')->dropDownList($listTokens, [
    'prompt' => ['text' => 'Please select', 'options' => ['value' => 'none']],
    'onchange' => '$.post(...)',
]);
```

[Подробная информация в документации](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml#dropDownList()-detail)

Comment: Мне нужно что бы в форме ` ['onchange' => '$.post("'.Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(["site/adds"])....... ]` , было еще, а dropDownList можно только 2 параметра передоверять если я не ошибаюсь, СПАСИБО за помощь

Comment: `onchange` у вас находится в массиве, в этот массив вы можете добавлять и другие значения, в том числе и `prompt`.

Comment: Спасибо работает, а можно еще вопрос, а можно так сделать при  обновление оставлялся выбранное значения, я так понял  нужно здесь дописывать `'prompt' => ['text' => 'Please select', 'options' => ['value' => 'none']],`

Comment: При обновлении чего и какое значение? Переформулируйте нормально свой вопрос.

Comment: Например из выпадающего я выбрал 2 оно оправилось например get параметром `<option avlue=2 selected= selected>name</optin>`

Answer (score 0):

В контроллере:

`$listTokens = ['' => 'Выберите значения'] + ArrayHelper::map(FbToken::find()->where(['user_id' => Yii::$app->user->getId()])->all(), 'token', 'name');`

остальное без изменений